# Why is my outlet nil?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm having trouble with a cocoa project. I'm displaying a keyboard composed of NSButtons, and I'd like that when I click on one of the keys, the label is added to a NSTextField. I have a controller that I use as a singleton, so each key "knows" how to access the controller. In the controller, I have an outlet linked to the NSTextField. When I click on a key, nothing happens. So I used something like `NSLog(@"%@", [[[OakController] sharedInstance] textarea])` on a mouseDown event, and in the console output, I get `(null)`.

Long story short, my outlet is set to nil, and I don't know why it is that way, or how to solve that...

Here's the code of the controller : https://gist.github.com/1090564. Sorry for the lack of syntax coloring.

Thanks for reading guys!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you actually have multiple instances of OakController instead of one like you expect. Did you drag a blue cube into your IB document and change its custom class to OakController? That will allocate and initialize a new object each time. I'd guess that your sharedInstance method also allocates and initializes an instance.

Try adding an awakeFromNib method to OakController, and add a break point. Log self's pointer value. In your second case were the outlet is unexpectedly nil, also log self's pointer address.

Comment: Yep, I dragged the blue cube and changed its class. And yes again, I got two different pointer values, one from awakeFromNib, and the other when i click on keys

Comment: @Katen: Then that's the reason your outlet is nil: You have two different objects. In the object inside your nib, the outlet is set. In the object outside your nib, it is not.

Comment: How do I fix that ? Is my singleton class not correctly implemented ?

Comment: @Katen: While you need to set `__shared_instance`, it doesn't fix your problem. This is the correct explanation.

Comment: Ok, I know the why. Still need to find out how to fix it though. Looks like I cannot create different instances (when I use [[OakController alloc] init] twice in a row, it returns me the same pointer), but that somehow the nib can.