# Initiating outlets when there is no xib file

Tags: ios, iboutlet

I have defined the `RPM` class which inherits from `UIView`

```
@interface RPM : UIView
```

this class doesnot have any xib file, but has two outlets defined in its header file:

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) IBOutlet Analog* outletOne;

@property (nonatomic,assign) IBOutlet Analog* outletTwo;
```

where Analog is a class inherited from UIView.

As I run the application, the two outlets are `nil` when I reach the `awakeFromNib` method. Because there is no xib file, I cannot use the method suggested here (i.e. dragging the outlet to the view):
 [Why is my outlet nil?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6739118/why-is-my-outlet-nil)

How should I tell the class to initiate the outlets?

Comment: They aren't outlets. They are properties of a `UIView` subclass. Only if you're using a NIB can they become outlets. If you don't use a NIB, you'll have to initialize the views yourself.

Comment: The answer is, that they should have been associated to another UIviewer, by dragging them to that viewer. So, here, although they themselved did not have xib files, I could have associated them to another xib so they would be initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Initialize your properties in `initWithFrame`.

You can delete the IBOutlet keywords.